# Gradle application build does not include own jar

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm using gradle to build an application in Kotlin.
When I run the `distTar` task it successfully builds a tar file but fails to include the application itself.

My build.gradle files looks like this (Somewhat shrunk down because it's from a multi module project originally):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.3.41' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.41' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen' version '1.3.41' apply false
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE' apply false
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8.0'

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'

    // a whole load more of dependencies

    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
}

distTar {
    archiveFileName = 'core.tar'
}

mainClassName = 'core.Application'
```

The final tar archive includes a lib folder with all my dependencies but not the application jar itself.

Comment: it seems to have something to do with the spring boot plugin since builds without that are running fine